# soxを使って無音部分を削除するには？

Tags: windows-10, コマンドプロンプト

windows 10 64bit環境です。
１～２秒程度の音声ファイルから
音声最後に若干残る無音部分を削除したいのですが、
どのように記述すれば良いのでしょうか？

無音部分の長さはランダムなので自動で無音部分を検知して
削除する必要があるのですが、

```
sox input.wav output.wav fade 0 1.0 0.5
```

これだと無音でない部分もカットされてしまいます。
良い方法をご教授いただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

試していませんが、silenceオプションを使えばできるかも知れません。

http://forums.justlinux.com/showthread.php?136678-using-sox-to-trim-silence-from-the-end-of-wav-files

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみたいと思います。